# Facebook iFrame Tab - Scroll to top

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe

I've created a facebook iFrame tab, and it shows my html (located at my server), but i'm trying to scroll the window to the top when i click a image. Any ideas?

Comment: Unclear why this has so many downvotes... It's not the best question, but it's a legit question, totally appropriate for SO... (Upvoted!)

Answer (score 14):

```
FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
```

[Facebook SDK Reference > JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/)

Answer (score 1):

As new Facebook pages were introduced when you use: FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0); it pulls the page up to the cover image, and you will see only a little bit of the FB tab app (if you are using small screen). In order to bring only the tab app to the top, I am using: 
FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,360);